# Get Comment list from selected post jsonplaceholder.typicode.com api

Tags: php, android, ios, json, web-services

I am looking for your advice/Guidance with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/.

I am getting list of posts from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts as below

```
    [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      },
    ...
]
```

Now I am trying to fetch comment for a selected post but I can't find a way to fetch list of comments associated post.

Please guide me how can I list of comments from a selected post.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post/{post_id}/comments
```

send the id for post in the placeholder and you are good to go.  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post/1/comments will fetch you all the comments for post with id as 1